# MySQL Query to Retrieve Rows with Maximum Date for Each Combination

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, go-gorm

I have a MySQL database with a `candidate_stages`. It contains information about candidates' progress through various stages and processes. Each record includes a name, stage_id, process_id, and date. I'm trying to calculate TAT(Turn around time) for each process.

Here's an example of my table structure and data:

```
CREATE TABLE candidate_stages (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    stage_id INT,
    process_id INT,
    date DATE
);

INSERT INTO candidate_stages VALUES
(1, 'abc', 101, 1001, '2024-02-01'),
(2, 'abc', 102, 1001, '2024-02-01'),
(3, 'abc', 103, 1001, '2024-02-02'),
(4, 'abc', 201, 1002, '2024-02-02'),
(5, 'abc', 202, 1002, '2024-02-03'),
(6, 'abc', 103, 1001, '2024-02-04');
(7, 'abc', 201, 1002, '2024-02-05');
```

TAT: Turnaround time (TAT) refers to the total time it takes to complete a process, from the point of initiation to the point of completion

The result I am expecting is:

```
process_id | number_of_days
----------------------------
1001       | 2
1002       | 0
```

The Turn Around Time (TAT) for process 1001 is 2, accounting for the transition from 2024-02-01 to 2024-02-02. Additionally, the user underwent another transfer to process 1001 on 2024-02-04, and this process change took 1 day, resulting in a total TAT of 2 days.

process_id 1002 has 0 number_of_days because there is no process after it.

Could someone help me with the correct MySQL query to achieve this result? Thank you!

Comment: You need to explain the date math better.  If I take the earliest 1001 date '2024-02-01' and date diff it between 2024-02-04 I get 3 days.  So I don't see how you get 2.  and for 1002 I get 2024-02-02 from 2024-0205 and I get 3 days as well.  So the business rules are not well defined.

Comment: @xQbert I have added the explanation in the question.

Comment: I don't see how the records relate and the date math works I see 4 records for 1001, 3 for 1002.  you're not taking the min /max dates and doing a date diff... in 1002 when you say it's 0 days, there's 1day difference between 02-02 and 02-03 so why isn't it being counted? Using plain english, describe the rules/requirements that determine if a date is used in calculating turn around time.  I can't see a formula/rules which would result in your expected results.

Comment: Given how process_ID 1001 is calculated why woudln't processID 1002 be 2024-2-4 MINUS 2024-02-02 resulting in 2 days PLUS line 7 but since it's yet "Open" we don't have a end date to calculate.  Are you saying The row order matters and that the end date of a process is the start date of the next process?  thus records 1-3 END on 2024-02-02, records 4-5 start on 2024-02-02 and end on -2024-02-04? but since the process ID 1002 is yet "Open" due to line 7 we show days of zero

Comment: are they paired values so when I see 1001 the 1st entry is a start, the 2nd is the end, 3rd would be a start and 4th would be an end?  no; becuase you say 1001 goes from 2024-02-01 to 2024-02-02...   so yeah I can't see the pattern.  Without that; I've no idea how to accomplish what's desired.